# Update and replace string values according to pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing a complex sql update case which I can't figure out how to solve.

I have column of type `nvarchar(32)` which consists of numbers like "952683174". I do need to replace its string according to the following rules:

- 1 replace with 3
- 2 replace with 5
- 3 replace with 4
- 4 replace with 1
- 5 replace with 9
- 6 replace with 8
- 7 replace with 2
- 8 replace with 3
- 9 replace with 6

So the previous column value "952683174" will be "695834321" after performing the update query on the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first replace each number with another character, and then replace the character with the corresponding number as follows:

```
DECLARE @number nvarchar(32) = '952683174';

SELECT
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
@number,
'1', 'A'),'2', 'B'),'3', 'C'),'4', 'D'),'5', 'E'),'6', 'F'),'7', 'G'),'8', 'H'),'9', 'I'),
'A', '3'),'B', '5'),'C', '4'),'D', '1'),'E', '9'),'F', '8'),'G', '2'),'H', '3'),'I', '6')
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/KWFQWZ52013)

Comment: This was my original approach as well, +1.

Comment: @MatSnow
Thanks for your help, but how can I combine this with an update statement. i.e. to go through all the columns values and update it according to this rule?

Comment: @Dana You can replace `@number` with the columnname in the update statement. Like: `UPDATE yourTable SET yourColumn = REPLACE(REPLACE..., yourColumn, '1', 'A'), '2', 'B')...`

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: This works for SQL Server 2017 and above.

`TRANSLATE` function.

```
select TRANSLATE(yourcolumn,'123456789','354198236') FROM yourtable;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b28da/141)

Comment: No. Translate was introduced in 2017. The question is about 2008 version.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : I'm sorry.. didn't know.. I  will probably keep this answer with a disclaimer which might help in future!.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of SQL Server have better solutions for this - such as the `Translate` built in function introduced in 2017 version.

However, since this is 2008 version, you have to manipulate the string yourself.

My suggested solution is to use a table for translations, not quite the same as DhruvJoshi's answer (I think mine is simpler), but a very similar approach.

Having said that, here is another approach, that doesn't use `replace` at all:

First, create and populate the sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Col nvarchar(32)
)

INSERT INTO @T (Col) VALUES 
('952683174'),
('123456789'),
('06432') -- added more values to make sure I didn't mess it up
```

Then, create and populate the translation table:

```
DECLARE @Translate AS TABLE
(
    original char(1),
    translation char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Translate (original, translation) VALUES
('1', '3'),
('2', '5'),
('3', '4'),
('4', '1'),
('5', '9'),
('6', '8'),
('7', '2'),
('8', '3'),
('9', '6')
```

Now, using a stacked cte as a tally table replacement (you can use an actual tally table if you have one, of course. If not, read Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)), `cross apply` and left join to do the translation, and `for xml path` as string_agg (another function finally built in 2017 version), you can do it like this:

```
;WITH  E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) V(v)), --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4)

SELECT  Col, 
        (
            SELECT ISNULL(translation, c)
            FROM @T as t1
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT Substring(Col, N, 1) As c, translation
                FROM cteTally
                LEFT JOIN @Translate ON Substring(Col, N, 1) = original
                WHERE N <= LEN(ISNULL(Col, ''))
            ) as t2
            WHERE t1.Col = t0.Col
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) As translated
FROM @T t0
```

Results:

```
col         translated
952683174   695834321
123456789   354198236
06432       08145 -- Note that the 0 doesn't get translated...
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/AGD50078)

Key benefits of my solution, compared to the other answer currently provided:

1. All set based approach, no use of replace or string manipulation.
2. All translations are stored as table values. Nothing is hard-coded.
3. Translation values are not limited to one char. If you decide to translate 9 to 11, that will only require you to change the translation table (MatSnow's answer also have this benefit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like below:
<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/PNAGT14944)**</kbd>
Explanation is inline in comments

```
create table numbers (n nvarchar(32));
insert into numbers values ('952683174'),('5785348');
-- 1. We create ordering on numbers to retain original order
; with ordered_numbers
as
(
    select 
        n, 
        r= row_number() over(order by (SELECT NULL)) 
    from numbers
),
-- 2. we create a tally table to split out each digit position wise and replace with mapping in V(old,new)
cte as 
(
    select 
        newdigit= v.new,r
    from 
        ordered_numbers
    cross apply 
        (
            select 
            top (select LEN(n)) 
                row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn
            from
                sys.objects o1 cross join sys.objects o2)tally
            join 
            (
                values
                   ('1','3'),
                   ('2','5'),
                   ('3','4'),
                   ('4','1'),
                   ('5','9'),
                   ('6','8'),
                   ('7','2'),
                   ('8','3'),
                   ('9','6')
                )v(old,new)
    on  v.old=SUBSTRING(n,rn,1) 
 )
--3. We join back the digits into a single string using order created in step 1
SELECT n = REPLACE((
            select '|' + newdigit
            from cte c1
            where c1.r=c2.r
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),'|','')
FROM cte c2
group by c2.r
order by c2.r asc
```